# Didn't Branch and Poppy already become a couple in the first Trolls movie?

Tags: trolls, trolls-world-tour

In *Trolls World Tour*, Branch spends most of the movie trying to/planning to tell Poppy about his feelings for her.

However, during the ending of the first *Trolls* movie, didn't he and Poppy already become a couple? And didn't he already confess his feelings in the first movie? Why is he still trying to in the second?

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no. Although they share a personal connection at the end of Trolls, there's no good indication that they began dating or that their relationship went beyond becoming *really good friends*.

It's not until subsequent films (*Trolls World Tour*) that Branch finally accepts that his feelings for her are romantic in nature and it's not until *Trolls Holiday* that he actually kisses her for the first time.

> **SC:** *Trolls World Tour did a great job setting up that all the Troll tribes had by the end of the film embraced each other’s differences. We were really excited to show them all gathering together as one big Troll family, highlighting this progression of togetherness and acceptance among all Trolls. We also wanted to highlight that Poppy and Branch’s relationship had taken the next step, clearly showing them as boyfriend and girlfriend. Even showing their first Kiss!*
>
> **TH:** *We met so many incredible new characters in Trolls World Tour and
> we were very excited about the idea of bringing them all together to
> celebrate a Holiday in Pop Village. Also, with Branch and Poppy
> becoming “official” at the end of TWT, we knew this would be the
> perfect time to explore what being in a relationship looks like for
> them — and how they both uniquely approach the idea of finding the
> ‘perfect gift’ for the person they love the most.*
>
> <sub><sup>[INTERVIEW: “Trolls Holiday In Harmony” Directors On New TV Special](https://www.animationscoop.com/interview-trolls-holiday-in-harmony-directors-on-new-tv-special/)</sup></sub>